# Bootstrap affix scroll issue with IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I have a problem with a sidebar on my website. I'm using Bootstrap affix to make it fixed until the end of the page where it should come up with the rest of the content at a certain point...

It's working perfectly fine with Chrome and Safari but with Firefox or IE, the sidebar is not always moving up with the content at the end of the scroll...When I scroll slowly, it's working fine, but if I scroll too fast, the bottom of the sidebar will cover the footer.

[This is a page](http://soluxor.ca/dev/www/supalloy.com/fr/materiaux/alliages-de-nickel/) where you can see it in action.

I can't find any information related to that issue. Anyone can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in Bootstrap that was resolved here: https://github.com/iainvdw/bootstrap/commit/c786f454c9175cce5bcf9a7074a3e206533b3d1a

However it doesn't seem it is included with the 3.1.1 version used on your site.

To do it manually, replace this line:

```
offsetBottom != null && (position.top + this.$element.height() >= scrollHeight - offsetBottom) ? 'bottom' :
```

With this:

```
offsetBottom != null && (Math.ceil(position.top) + this.$element.height() >= scrollHeight - offsetBottom) ? 'bottom' :
```

Comment: Have just been bug fixing an existing Bootstrap (3.1.1) site - this solution worked perfectly and solved our issue on Firefox and IE. THANKS!